# Algorith for Search and Save from Tree Structured Datatype in MongoDB

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb

Hi, I have arranged my document in Tree structure in MongoDB using Reference. For example, I have one `ClassRoom` it contains name field and set of `Students`. Each student contains their own student details with `Address`. Address Class contains street, ect..

I have given the reference of students in classroom object. And reference of address in student object using `@DBRef` from Spring-Data-MongoDB. All these data is in same Collection.  Now My data arragement is tree like structure.

Now i'm looking for 2 clarifications,

1. During search i have class room name and student name. With this details i only want mark field from student object and street field from address object from Student..??

Work Around: using mongoTemplate if i search class room and using java code i'm comparing and fetching the data. Its not a good idea, because loading whole object into memory as well traversing the object using java will create performance drawback. How to write single query to fetch particular data field from MongoDB.

2. While saving the class room object, i'm first manually saving all address and student last classroom.In real time i'll get large object. I'm suppose to save the leaf first. Bottom to Up design..Can any one suggest me how to handle these situations ..?? Any algorithm in Springs or inbuild fn in MongoDB ..??

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you should read this about embedded and normalized data models: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/data-model-design/#data-modeling-referencing

Comment: And this: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/data-models-tree-structures/

Comment: Thanks for this link..i already went throw this doc..From this only i have designed my Object like this..Now i'm facing performance issue..when i'm searching and saving.

Comment: No wonder you have performance issues when you use MongoDB as if it were a relational database. Use embedding instead of referencing whenever possible, or you have to pay the price.

Comment: @Philipp - Is there any direct single query to filter particular data from different document as like my prob 1 above..i'm lot working around for that..As well i'm scaning the whole object and saving from the leaf this too working around any suggestions to overcome ??-Thanks

Comment: You're trying to do a join on the DB. There's no workaround. You need to perform queries in distinct steps if you need to connect relationships from distinct documents. MongoDb may not be the right choice for your application.